# scala match from list of Boolean to list of summed Int

Tags: scala

I have a general question about scala/spark's list matching. Say I have a List of Boolean in the form of:

```
List(true, false, false ,true, true)
```

I wish to convert this List of Boolean to something like:

```
List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

such that each time there is a true, the List adds 1, and each time there is a false, it outputs the previous result. I think there are some really efficient ways to do this without looping, but cannot think of any right now..

Comment: yes, add one when true

Comment: How is this related to apache-spark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `scanLeft` for this:

```
List(true, false, false, true, true).scanLeft(0) { case (sum, next) =>
    if(next) sum + 1 else sum
}.tail

res45: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

`scanLeft` helps you generate a sequence of partial sums, which is essentially what you have here. In `case (sum, next)`, `sum` represents the current accumulated value, and `next` represents the next element in the `List`. So we check of `next` is true, and if so add one, otherwise return the current sum. Each element returned within `scanLeft` is added to the final `List`.

Note that I had to seed it with `0`, which I dropped at the end by taking only the `tail` of the `List`. Otherwise I would have had `List(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: I think `tail` would be a bit clearer than `drop(1)`.

Comment: I suppose. It's really borderline.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are looking for scanLeft:

```
val bs = List(true, false, false, true, true)
val is = bs.scanLeft(0){ case (acc, el) => if (el) acc + 1 else acc }.tail
// "is" is equal to List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you take the full list and not the tail, the result is `List[Int] = List(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)` because of the starting value 0.

Here is the [scaladoc for scanLeft](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@scanLeft%5BB,That%5D%28z:B%29%28op:%28B,A%29=%3EB%29%28implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom%5BRepr,B,That%5D%29:That).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I've never used scanLeft, often had to resolve to duplicating, removing the first/last and zip them together. Nice one